# Is it possible to just share a single Chrome tab in a Zoom Call?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, zoom-meeting

Is it possible to just share a single chrome tab during a zoom call? It seems right now when I share all the tabs seem to get shared with the remote viewers.

Is there a workaround for this?

In case it matters, this is on Win 10.

Comment: You can drag a tab out of chrome to move it to a new window. You should be able to share just that window, effectively sharing only one tab.